# Fancybox - disable right click

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I would like to disable right-click within Fancybox and I've tried without success to integrate solutions posted here (and elsewhere) into my Fancybox code.

My Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#fancybox-manual-a").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open([
                {
                    href : 'images/img1.jpg',
                    title : 'Title 1'
                }, {
                    href : 'images/img2.jpg',
                    title : 'Title 2'
                }, {
                    href : 'images/img3.jpg',
                    title: 'Title 3'
                }
            ], {
                helpers : {
                    title : {
                        type : 'over'
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The code snippet that has been suggested through several sources is as follows:

```
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        beforeShow: function () {
            /* Disable right click */
            $.fancybox.wrap.bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
                    return false; 
            });
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately, my Fancybox application differs slightly from what I've seen posted elsewhere and I've not been able to successfully integrate this code snippet into my code.  Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: Did you replace the `.fancybox` selector in the snippet with `#fancybox-manual-a`?

Comment: Disabling the right mouse button is not possible in some browsers. And all it will achieve is pissing off your users that use it for navigation.